# Select all checkboxes does not work on next page in JQuery datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I am using JQuery datatables. I want to add select all column with checkboxes so that when I click on 'select all' check box all the checkboxes on that page should get selected.

I am using the following code:

```
<table id="myTable" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> Name</th>
            <th> Type</th>
            <th> Details</th>
            <th>Select <input type="checkbox" name="select_all" value="1" id="select-all"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($test as $data) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $data->name; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $data->type; ?></td>
            <td><a href="/details">view details</a></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="manuf[]" class="sub_chk" data-id="<?php echo $data->id; ?>"></td>


        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#myTable').DataTable();
});

$('#select-all').on('click', function(e) {
if($(this).is(':checked',true))  
{
    $(".sub_chk").prop('checked', true);  
}  
else  
{  
    $(".sub_chk").prop('checked',false);  
}  
});
</script>
```

The above code works for the first page of the datatable but if I select the second page and if I select 'Select all' checkbox, it takes me to the first page instead of selecting the checkboxes in the second page.

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/UvjnT/1475/)**

The problem comes from the sort, you should disable the sort in the `th` that contain the select all checkbox.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah you're right, my mistake. I didn't realise the content was being dumped in the page on load, I thought it was coming from AJAX as it really should be when doing paging.

Comment: @Zakaria Acharki It does not work .. let me explain it again There is a jquery datatable with all data and a column with checkboxes and its header has another checkbox (to select all checkboxes on that page). If I am on the first page I click select all All the rows get checked. That is correct, But when I go to next page of the datatable the header select all checkbox remains selected. If I unselect it, it takes me to the first page of datatable instead of selecting the checkboxes of the second page..

Comment: I think the problem comes from the sort, try to disable the sort on the `th` that has the `select-all` checkbox, http://jsfiddle.net/UvjnT/1475/

Comment: Thanks removing sort worked but the checkbox remains in the previous state how can I set it back , Meaning if I am on the first page of the jquery datatable, I select the select all checkbox from the th , then I go to the next page , On the next page the select all checkbox from the th header still remains as checked How do I maintain the state on it on each page, for example if I do select all on the second page and go to third page , The third page should not show as checked But if i come back to 2nd page it should show as checked

Answer (score 0):

i hope this link helps you with your problems.
thanks

> http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-how-to-add-a-checkbox-column/

Comment: You have sufficient reputation to imply a degree of familiarity with the site and its expectations that answers be self-contained and not be entirely reliant on a link to an external site. Please include the relevant parts of that site, summarised, in your answer showing how, and why, it's relevant to the specific question you're attempting to answer.